# Can't download image from https links with requests. Keep getting a SSL certificate error

Tags: ssl, python-requests

My code is the following.

```
import requests

url = 'https://images.metmuseum.org/CRDImages/ad/web-large/194083.jpg'
name = url.split('/')[-1]
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
if r.status_code == 200:
    with open(name, 'wb') as f:
       for chunk in r.iter_content():
           f.write(chunk)
```

The SSL error is: "HTTPSConnectionPool(host='images.metmuseum.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /CRDImages/li/web-large/li120.5%20W48.R.jpg (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))"

It does works with other urls, but it doesn't work with this one. I also can download the images with Chrome.

I've already tried using quests.get(url,verify=False,stream=True) but it just downloads broken jpg images(a blank square). Currently using anaconda,. Python,certifi,requests are all up-to-date.